# Prevent Material UI "Select" component from hiding other elements on screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a Material UI Select component (version 5.14.11) within my own React custom component, as shown in the code snippet below.

```
       <Select 
            sx={{ width: 400}}
            id="id-case"
            value={case || "placeholder"}
            label="Cases"
            onChange={caseChanged}
        >
            <MenuItem key={-1} value="placeholder"><em>Please select a case</em></MenuItem>
            {cases && cases.map((case, i) => {     
                return (<MenuItem key={i} value={case.name}>{case.name}</MenuItem>)
            })}
        </Select>
```

Upon page load, the Select component is rendered correctly along with all the other UI elements of the page. When I click on the down arrow, the component expands to display the items available for selection. However, it also causes all other visual elements in the browser window to become hidden. All you see is the expanded Select component on a plain white background. When I select a list item or dismiss the expanded Select component, the other UI elements of the page become visible again.

In the Chrome Inspector, I've noticed that this attribute is added to the body element when the Select is in the expanded state:

> style="overflow: hidden;"

and this attribute is added to the div id="root" element:

> aria-hidden="true"

Both attributes are removed once more when the Select returns to its un-expanded state.

The behaviour I would like is that the other UI elements are still visible behind the expanded Select component. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?